# What does the transition matrice mean in Markovian processes?

Tags: matrices, markov-chains

> A diploma is organised by the College of Hogwarts on two years: $year1$ and $year2$. Each year an exam is organized in order to go to the upper level or be graduatie. Student has the probability $p$ to pass this exam. Those who fail repeat a year but must pass this time.
>
> A student current year is observed every year in september. How to modelize by a Markov chain the schooling of a student?

I thought that as far as a student can repeat only once a year and that there are 2 years in the diploma, if we call X the current year and $Y$ the previous year, it should be:

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
  1-p & p & 0 &\\
  0 & 1-p & p &\\
  0 & 0 & 1 &\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then I want to find the different possible states in 2011 of a student who registered in 2009 and their probability.

- Having failed twice
- Having failed the first time but not the second one
- Having passed the first time but failed the second
- Having passed both time.

As far as there is 2 years of difference I tried to build up the transitional matrice $P^2$:

$$P^2=\begin{pmatrix}
  (1-p)^2 & 2p(1-p) & p^2 &\\
  0 & (1-p)^2 & p(1-p)+p &\\
  0 & 0 & 1 &\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

**but here I don't understand what does $P(Y_2=j|X_0=i)$ means anymore.**

The probability to have failed twice is $P(Y_2=1|X_0=1)=(1-p)^2$
The probability for one to have failed one's first year is $P(Y_2=2|X_=1)=2(1-p)p$ but why is it $2*...$(two times(1-p))? It doesn't make logically sense to me.
The probability for one to have failed one's second year is now: $P(Y_2=2|X_2=2)$, but I don't understand the result either...

Comment: I have some troubling reading the last part due to wording/formatting. Specifically the second to last sentence. Maybe you want double check what you wanted to write.

Comment: @OFRBG, is it clearer now?

Comment: Remember that the transition matrix tells you what is the probability of moving from state $i$ to state $j$. When you calculate the $n$-th power, you can read the probability of going from state $i$ to state $j$ in $n$ steps, considering all the routes. For example, if you need to find the probability of ending up in the second year after two years, you get $2p(1-p)$ because there are two ways of getting there: passing and then failing ($p(1-p)$) or conversely failing first year and passing second year, ($(1-p)p$). What the matrix tells you is probability of *being* there after $n$ steps.